# Building a Hadoop Job object for Hadoop Streaming

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to configure and run a Hadoop Streaming job from Java (the system I'm working with wants the Hadoop jobs to be callable by Java method).

I did find the `createJob` method in `org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob` ([http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/StreamJob.html#createJob(java.lang.String[])](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/StreamJob.html#createJob%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)), but this method returns a `JobConf` object, which has been deprecated. Is there any way to create a `Job` object for streaming, or to convert the `JobConf` to a `Job`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few JIRA tickets about porting the Streaming code to support the new API, but to my knowledge it has yet to be made generally available

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1122
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-3619

Note that even though the method of submitting old-api jobs using JobConf is deprecated, it's still supported in the latest 1.0.3 release of Hadoop.

Comment: Wow, very disappointing that a patch for this was first submitted nearly 2 years ago, and it still hasn't made it into trunk. Thanks for this reference, though.